# Override overflow-x hidden for a child element

Tags: html, css

I have a wrapper class with the following CSS properties;

```
#wrapper {
  margin-left: -320px;
  left: 350px;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 10px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
}

#wrapper.affix-top {
  position: fixed;
}
```

It is a left side-bar with scroll-y. Now I want a dropdown-menu-right, right at the end of wrapper. But since the property is `overflow-x: hidden`
Only partial dropdown is shown. How can I make the dropdown pop out without actually tampering with the wrapper? If I remove overflow-x, the dropdown comes inside the div and is accessed using scroll, but I want the dropdown popping out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you need overflow set to auto:

```
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
```

With overflow auto, the scroll appears only if it's needed.

Comment: dropdown-menu-right is towards the right side. Hence overflow-x:hidden needs to be changed. If I change it to auto it creates a scroll inside the and the dropdown-menu-right does not pop out